# How to configure networking from .net?

Tags: .net, networking, configuration, mono

I am writing a small application to help people join an OpenVPN network. What it needs to do:

- Set the IP address
- Set the netmask
- Manipulate routes
- Create bridge between 2 interfaces (I don't even know the command line for this.)

Are there any classes in .net that provide this funcionality or do I need to run netsh or some other configuration program? If there are such classes are they usable in mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no classes. You can p/invoke the Windows network API or you can fork a process to invoke netsh.